# How can I prevent Tyrus websocket client reconnect logic from resulting in multiple open sockets?

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I've seen this behavior occur occasionally and I can't reproduce it consistently. But it appears that the reconnect logic in Tyrus (v1.10) can result in multiple open sockets/threads for the same client.

The process that results in multiple sockets connected looks like this:

1. Client opens web socket to server.
2. Server reboots/becomes unavailable for a short time.
3. Client begins trying to reconnect.
4. Server becomes available again.
5. Two+ threads obtain active web sockets to the server.

My reconnect handler looks like:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDisconnect(CloseReason reason)
    {
        LOG.info("Reconnect handler captured close event. Reason: " + reason);
        if(!reconnect)
        {
            LOG.info("Not attempting to reconnect. Closing the latch");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.info("Attempting to reconnect.");
            return true; // reconnect
        }
    }
```

I could try to solve this problem on the server side and validate each connection is unique to the client, but then I'd have to synchronize down to a single thread for new connections and that doesn't even solve the case of load balanced servers.

Comment: Hi Preson, could we move this discussion to Tyrus mailing list - tyrus@users.java.net? if not .. could you please provide some proof that there are 2 client connections? It should not happen, so if you have more details, feel free to open new bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS

Comment: After setting up a test environment to replicate the issue I believe the actual issue I'm seeing is manifestation of this issue: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57969

I would see multiple connections/logging messages from the same client on the server side assuming that meant multiple sockets were being created. But it appears the @PathParam annotated params are not thread-safe, so when multiple distinct clients reconnected they all appeared to be the same client in the server logs.